# Apache2 won't start, ulimit error?

Tags: apache, apache2

Here's the log from trying to start apache2:

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                     
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I'm new to running my own Apache. Any idea what's causing this failure?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following command please: sudo su wwwdata -c 'ulimit -a' Replace wwwdata with the correct name of the service user if it is different.

Comment: Hmm, I got "su: invalid option -- 'a'" and removed the flag and got "Unknown id: ulimit".

Comment: Sorry, put the -c in the wrong spot.  Try again, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Still getting "su: invalid option -- 'a'"

Comment: Edited again, sorry about that.  I've put the command and its option in single quotes, this should work now.

Comment: Got back this:
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        8192
coredump(blocks)     0
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
locked memory(kbytes) 64
process              7885
nofiles              1024
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
locks                unlimited

Comment: time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        8192
coredump(blocks)     0
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
locked memory(kbytes) 64
process              95885
nofiles              1024
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
locks                unlimited

Answer (score 10):

Use sudo for starting apache server, the issue if due to permissions :

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: Please check if port 80 is already in use, search for netstat command on net.